# Given groups identified by a dictionary, form groups of keys that have values in common (inverse grouping)

Tags: python, dictionary, grouping

Let's say I have a dictionary

`d = {k1:[v1,v2,v4], k2:[v1,v5,v6], k3:[v2,v5], k4:[v1,v6,v5]}`

All keys in the dictionary can be identified with groups (of items contained in corresponding lists), so `k1` group contains `v1,v2,v4`. I want to form groups with the `v`'s as the keys and `k`'s as the values, such that the items contained in the `vi` group would be all the original keys that contained `vi` in their groups. So the desired output would be

`{v1:[k1,k2,k4], v2:[k1,k3], v4:[k1], v5:[k2,k3,k4], v6:[k2,k4]}`

Is there an efficient way to do so? I'm struggling to come up with a way that the above operation can be done for large dictionaries, so would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't care the order of the result or the type of value.You could use `defaultdict` and `set`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(set)

d = {"k1": ["v1", "v2", "v4"], "k2": ["v1", "v5", "v6"], "k3": ["v2", "v5"], "k4": ["v1", "v6", "v5"]}
for key,values in d.items():
    for value in values:
        result[value].add(key)

# defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'v1': {'k4', 'k2', 'k1'}, 'v2': {'k3', 'k1'}, 'v4': {'k1'}, 'v5': {'k3', 'k2', 'k4'}, 'v6': {'k2', 'k4'}})
```

After get the result,change it to a normal dictionary(the value is `list`) if necessary:

```
converted_result = {key: list(values) for key, values in result.items()}
# {'v1': ['k1', 'k2', 'k4'], 'v2': ['k1', 'k3'], 'v4': ['k1'], 'v5': ['k3', 'k2', 'k4'], 'v6': ['k2', 'k4']}
```

Comment: Order of result doesn't matter, but what do mean by not caring about the type of value?

Comment: @user9343456 The `set` means unordered and there doesn't have duplicate elements.(the value couldn't be changed).